# Как аккуратно отобразить время оставшееся до даты Х?

Tags: c

Имеется переменная `struct tm *time` , как аккуратно и просто отобразить в человеко читаемом виде сколько осталось до этой даты от даты которая хранится в другой переменной (`struct tm *stime`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если недалеко :) - то перевести их в `time_t` вызовом `mktime`, вычесть, и разницу в секундах разделить на дни, часы, минуты...

Comment: Ага, вот в чем у меня проблема была, я поленился и пытался не сам разделить, а через gmtime. Недалеко))